# SocialAuth hardcode account

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering if it's possible to hardcode a facebook account in SocialAuth-Android.
My app parses my company's Facebook page for feeds and the reason why I want to implement a hardcoded facebook account, is so that the user doesn't have to log in with their Facebook credentials if they don't want to.

If so, how can i hardcode a facebook account (username and password) in SocialAuth.

Comment: Hi Socialauth android uses oauth. It means you don't require facebook app install on your system. it is a secure ways of using social networks.